# How do i solve $E(7+8X+X^2)$?

Tags: random-variables

I'm trying to solve the expected value of the random variable $E(7+8X+X^2)$. What I do know is that $E(X)=5$, and the variance is $Var(X)=2$.

Comment: Use the linearity of the mean, and that the variance is the mean of the square minus the square of the mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $\mathbb{E}[X]=5$ and $\text{Var}[X]=\mathbb{E}[(X-5)^2]=2$. Since
$$ X^2+8X+7 = (X-5)^2+18 X-18 \tag{1}$$
by the additivity of the expected value it follows that
$$ \mathbb{E}[X^2+8X+7]= 18\left(\mathbb{E}[X]-1\right)+\text{Var}[X] = 18\cdot 4+2=\color{red}{74}.\tag{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the fact that variance is defined as $\sigma^2=E(x^2)-[E(x)]^2$, expectation is linear and the expectation of a constant is the constant.
$$E(7+8x+x^2)=E(7)+8E(x)+E(x^2)=7+8*5+E(x^2)=47+\sigma^2+[E(x)]^2=47+2+25=74$$

Comment: I think you miscalculated there. It should be $E(x^2)=\sigma^2+(E(x))^2$

Comment: @MarvinF. Oops fixing